# Matching the latest occurrence

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match

```
(abc123)^2+abc+def => (abc123)^2
(a1)^2+a+(b2)^2 => (a1)^2, (b2)^2
(b2)(b2) + (a1)^2 ==> (a1)^2
```

I have this regex `(\(.+?\))(\^\d+)` but it does not work for the second and third case.

Comment: Huh? [Yes it does (for the second).](https://regex101.com/r/nnto1N/1) I however can't see why the third case is valid.

Comment: @Vallentin it should matches all (...)^..., however it just matches ()()()^...

Comment: Try adding the `g` and `m` flags for global and multiline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted for a slightly more strict regex, allowing only numbers or letters, and then however many numbers after the `^`.

```
\([^\(\)]+?\)\^\d+?
```

[Regex101 Example](https://regex101.com/r/bvc6bD/2)

Comment: the characters in the brackets can be anything, and not only letters followed by numbers. I just simplified it as an example.

Comment: @kaien, I've modified it so that it will not match any "(" or ")" inside of the pattern. Check the updated example

Comment: Looks very similar to mine and edited half an hour after my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.` you could use `\w` (based on your string).

```
(\(\w+\))(\^\d+)
```

[**Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/nnto1N/3)

Comment: the characters in the brackets can be anything, and not only letters followed by numbers. I just simplified it as an example

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following regex

```
\([^)]+?\)\^\d+
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/Pye5wc/3/) with explanation